# JQuery slider position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had this little jquery slidercode for my headerslider. As u can see the previous image drops down to the next container. I just want keep it where it belongs and roll smooth. The main problem seems to be in my html/css cause JQuery looks pretty clean but somehow  $('.row1 > div:first') makes mistake and shows the previous img. The HTML and CSS might not be structured properly, but don't mind as slomo is better than nomo.

http://portfolio.jogabonito.fi

```js
  $(function() {

   $(".row1 > div:gt(0)").hide();

   setInterval(function() {
     $('.row1 > div:first')
       .fadeOut(1500)
       .next()
       .fadeIn(1500)
       .end()
       .appendTo('.row1');
   },  4000);

  });
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

[class*="col-"] {
 float: left;
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 
 
 
}

@font-face  {
 
 src:url(fonts/BebasNeue.otf);
 font-family:BebasNeue;
}

.row2 h3 {
 
 font-family:BebasNeue;
 font-size:2.5em;
 color:white;
 background-color:black;
 opacity:0.8;
 
}

.header {
 
 font-family:BebasNeue;
 font-size:5em;
 color:white;
 background-color:black;
 opacity:0.8;
 margin:10%;
 padding:2%;
 position:absolute;
    z-index: 3;
 
}

.caption {
 
 font-family:BebasNeue;
 font-size:2.5em;
 color:white;
 background-color:black;
 opacity:0.8;
 margin:20%;
 padding:2%;
 position:absolute;
    z-index: 3;
 
}



.container1{
 
 height:100vh;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);

}

.container2 {
 

 height:100vh;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 
}

.row1 {
 
 height:80vh;
 padding:2%;
 position:relative;
 
 
 
}

.row1 > div {
 
 width:100%;
 height:80vh;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 opacity:0.7;
 position:relative;
 
}

.row1 > div img {
 
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 
}

.row2 {
 
 height:50vh;
 
 
 
}

.row3 {
 
 height:10vh;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:BebasNeue;
 color:white;
 
}


.col-1 {
 
 width:33.33%;
 height:100%;
 margin:8%;
 background-color:tomato;
 opacity:0.8;

 
}



.col-12 {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 padding:2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to update this in your css:

```
.row1 > div {
    width:100%;
    height:80vh;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    opacity:0.7;
    position:absolute;
}
.row1 > div img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: i can not see that you have changed it .. its still same , change it and save it and let me know

Comment: yeah now it's runnin' thanks a lot! didn't work on my localhost maybe cause the caches :)